# All of array not showing?

Tags: php, arrays

OK, this is weird. I have an array of time blocks:

```
$time_block = array("09:00:00-13:00:00","10:00:00-14:00:00");
```

And I want to loop through them to create a start time and end time for each block:

```
foreach($time_block as $val)
{
    for($x = 0; $x < count($time_block); $x++)
    {
        $time=$val[$x];
        echo substr($time,0,8);
        echo "<br>";
        echo substr($time,-8);
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The end result should be:

```
09:00:00
13:00:00

10:00:00
14:00:00
```

But I am getting:

```
0
09
9

1
10
0
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as the correct answer so this question can be marked as resolved. If you still have issues with it, I would love to assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You wrote: `$time = $val[$x];`
`$val` is not an array, it's a string, and seems like you are doing a `foreach` and then a `for` on the same array?

You can use something like:

```
foreach ($timeblock as $timeString) {
     list($start, $end) = explode("-", $timeString);
     echo "$start $end\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($time_block as $v) {
   print_r(explode( '-',$v ));
   echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `foreach` loop, `$val` is a string.  When you ask for `$val[$x]`, your asking for the xth character of that string.  Probably not what you want.

**Solution:**

Take out the `for` statement, and change

```
$time=$val[$x];
```

to

```
$time=$val;
```

Comment: WOW we posted at the exact same time with seconds!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($time_block); $x++){
    $time = $time_block[$x];
    echo substr($time,0,8);
    echo "<br>";
    echo substr($time,-8);
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

You're using 2 nested loops while you only have 1 dimension in your data set. That should make you think.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem with your approach** is you're trying to loop through the element two times. If you use `foreach($time_block as $val)`, in every iteration `$val` will be a single element of the array. For example, on the first run, it will store `"09:00:00-13:00:00"`. So in your `for` loop, you were trying to loop through this `$val`, which is actually possible as strings can be accessed as arrays (the characters in the string being the elements).

**This will produce the exact output you needed**:

```
foreach($time_block as $val) {
    $t=explode('-', $val);
    echo $t[0]."<br>".$t[1]."<br><br>";
}
```

Here, [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is used to separate the time values in `$val` based on the `-` character. `$t` will be an array, holding the two times in `$val` as its two elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are double looping, just use it like this:

```
$time_block = array("09:00:00-13:00:00","10:00:00-14:00:00");
foreach($time_block as $time) {
   echo substr($time,0,8) . " ";
   echo substr($time,-8) . "\n";
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
09:00:00 13:00:00
10:00:00 14:00:00
```